# how to pass url to json and show a response to listview in android,how can i show in listview

Tags: android, android-json

//how to pass url to json and show a response to listview in android,how can i show in listview
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         InputStream is = null;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
         InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/");
        try {
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity httpEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
              is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch blockt
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i could not understand ur question url to json means? r u passing json object to server?

Comment: i want to send a request to that url after that i want to show json response in an listview format

Comment: ok u can encode url in json

Comment: after sending the url i got response,i donknow how can i put in listview format.can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response from the server and then use it to display the ListView.

The best way to do this would be to parse the JSON data and create an ArrayList, which can later pass to the adapter of the ListView.

There is an excellent **[tutorial (with full working code)](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)** on this very same topic.

Snippet from **[the tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)** :

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                            TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```